# Image width is not proper in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In my html the table which displays a red line. In Firefox I am getting the line correctly. But in IE the line has got its line height incremented.Showing in the images below.

```
<table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" summary="">
<tr>
<TD style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: red"><IMG alt="" src="myImage.gif" width=1 height=1>
</TD>
</tr>
</table>
```

In Firefox:

[image]

In IE:
[image]

Why is this happening or how can I fix it.

Comment: try `td {border-collapse: collapse}`

Comment: Have I missed something?

Comment: Try using .png instead of .gif The mere size of .gif files are sometimes causing browsers to simply not load the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it's better to apply css style border-bottom: 1px solid to this row.

```
<table style="width: 100%; text-align: center;" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>some column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 1px; line-height: 1px; border-bottom: 1px solid red; background: transparent;"><!-- border --></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/6jVvQ/6/

Answer (score 0):

Add this styles to your table row:

```
<tr style="height:1px; font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">
    <TD style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: red"><IMG alt="" src="myImage.gif" width=1 height=1>
    </TD>
</tr>
```

That's not to encourage inline styles though. Use external stylesheets!

Check out this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/En7qf/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" summary="">
    <tr>
        <td  style="height:1px; line-height:1px; background-color: red">
            <img alt="" src="myImage.gif" width="1px" height="1px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different solution. You don't have to use a table for this task.
You may want to use `div` or `hr`

It's less code and easier: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/6jVvQ/1/)

Tables considered deprecated (when styling your layout with them) and also you should avoid inline styling as much as you can.
If you are using tables anyway try to style them like this:

```
<table class="clean-table">
...
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
.clean-table{
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```